# Calling site theme Function instead of related theme function

Tags: magento-1.9

[image]

We called function **setproductlogin** in app/design/frontend/rwd/Theme/template/catalog/product  **list.phtml** :

```
 <div onclick="setproductlogin('<?php echo $_product->getEntityId()?>');setrequestlogin();">
   like</div>
```

and function **setproductlogin** script code is present in

app/design/frontend/rwd/**Theme**/template/productlike - **index.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setproductlogin(pid)
{
    document.getElementById("likeproduct_id").value=pid;
   jQuery("#productlistlogin").trigger("click");
}
</script>
```

app/design/frontend/rwd/**Theme**/layout/**productlike.xml** :

```
<reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="core/template" name="ajaxlogin">
                <action method="setTemplate"><template>productlike/index.phtml</template></action>                
            </block>
</reference>
```

We used same function in another theme [ Theme6] file  app/design/frontend/rwd/**Theme**6/template/aitcg - **js_styles1.phtml**

```
<button onclick="return setproductlogin(\'<?php echo Mage::registry("current_product")->getId()?>\', event);setrequestlogin();"  id="submit-editorApply-{{rand}}" >
SAVE DESIGN
</button>
```

we included same function code in same theme file as

app/design/frontend/rwd/**Theme6**/template/example/index.phtml ,

but still when we click "save design" button, its calling javascript function present in main theme [**Theme**] instead of related theme **Theme6**

**layout** file :

```
<reference name="content">     
<block type="example/list" name="examplelist" template="example/index.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Comment: Dont you think you should change in admin panel?..Like in the image you shared it says default is "Theme". It should be "Theme6". No?

Comment: in theme6 create same folder structure and file means `app/design/frontend/rwd/Theme6/template/productlike - index.phtml`

Comment: @KingshukDeb Thanks a lot for your comment, please support me like this in upcimg days also.... Gopal patel's suggestion worked for me.....

Comment: @GopalPatel Thanks a lot for your support, please post ur comment as an answer, i really really need your support like this in upcoming days also.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create same folder structure in **Theme6**

> app/design/frontend/rwd/Theme6/template/productlike/index.phtml